# Клик у ребенка закрывает родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок родитель и у него есть 1 ребенок

```
<div id="pop_bg">
<div id="pop_content">
</div>
</div>
```

Стоит событие клика на родителя, если кликаю на `pop_bg` то закрывается `pop_bg`, но беда в том , что когда я кликаю на контент ребенка (`pop_content`) - у меня срабатывает событие клика на `pop_bg`, и закрывается `pop_bg`, почему так? Как исправитть?

Comment: писать правильно код

Comment: добавьте javascript который используете, но вам наверняка нужен метод [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Учусь писать правильно, поэтому и спрашиваю как лучше

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так через `stopPropagation();`

```js
$('body').on('click', '#open', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#pop_bg").show();
});
$('body').on('click', '#pop_bg', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#pop_bg").hide();
});
$('body').on('click', '#pop_content', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

```css
#pop_bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}
#pop_content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="open">Open modal</a>
<div id="pop_bg">
  <div id="pop_content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

как вариант, можно написать так:

```
/*HTML*/
<div id="pop_bg">
<div id="pop_content">
</div>
</div>

/*CSS*/
#pop_bg {
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  background-color:#ccc;
   position:relative;
}

#pop_content {
  position:absolute;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  background-color:red;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

/*JS+JQUERY*/
$('#pop_bg').bind('click', function(e) {
 if (e.target.id != 'pop_bg') return false;
 $(this).hide();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxdOoO

Answer (score 0):

Версия без jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('#pop_bg').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (this === e.target) {
        // Ваш код
    }
});
```